# Keychain storage in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, keychain

For security reasons in iOS we are using Keychain to store passwords , certificates etc. Definitely it should store in secondary storage. Then only we are able to access that data later.

So my question is that where it is storing? I mean in which level? app level or device storage level or some where else?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on the keychain? Everything is explained there.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html

Comment: @Natarajan Whilst yes they should read that document, they are asking for something specific from it so would you like to reference where in that document it would help them.

Comment: @Natarajan I didn't find that. That's why i am asking. Can you tell me where can i find it exactly in the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stored at device level and the key chain can be shared across different apps.

Please refer to discussion of kSecAttrAccessGroup for sharing keychain entities @ https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html